# exception handling java user input

Tags: java, exception, user-input

I'am trying to put an exception in my code. But it doesnt work fully. Im trying for user to enter integers and then adding it to a list.

how come it only works for the first input? say if the first I enter 1.0 then it will raise the error. but if I put say `10, 1.0` it doesnt produce an error. and when i print the list. there is only the `10` well this is actually correct. but i want to make it so that if anything is entered other than integer it raise an error, and does not terminate. instead ask the user to try again.

this is what my code looks like

```
package basic.functions;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Percent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        reader.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");

        do {
            try {
                int n = reader.nextInt();
                list.add(Integer.valueOf(n));
            } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
                System.out.println("Not an integer, please try again");
            }
        }

        //When user press enter empty
        while (reader.hasNextInt());
        reader.close();
```

Comment: I still need some upvotes today; so I would love to have a real answer for you, but: I added `System.out.println("got: " + list);` after that close() statement ... and everything works fine. I can enter: 10 20 30 (with ENTER inbetween!) ... and 10, 20 , 30 is printed. Thus: unable to reproduce!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are running is a do-while which will execute once before checking the condition.

So, your first input is tried to be parsed into an integer to which you have handled the exception, thus printing the error message.

If you give a non-integer anywhere other than first time, your code will just terminate the loop before trying to parse the input.

Something like the following will give you the error message properly as you expect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    reader.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter Integer: ");

    while (true) {
        try {
            int n = reader.nextInt();
            list.add(Integer.valueOf(n));
        } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
            System.out.println("Not an integer, please try again. Press enter key to exit");
            if (reader.next().isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(list);
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: that works. Oh im just wondering, how do i make the code robust so that, instead of `break` the code ask the user for another try?

Comment: and why does that also print the exception?

Comment: it works, but its also printing the exception. why is that?

Comment: What exception is it printing?

Comment: the `("Not an integer, please try again")` from the exception handling

Comment: Because, its printed using System.out.println() :/

Comment: yea but the original specification that i wanted is that with the catch, i want to print why is it wrong. say if its not an integer i want to print tell the user

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to clearly understand what do you want. Your question said you wanted to catch the exception every time you type a non integer and I provided the code which will do that. If you want anything else, please add a new question. Ciao!

Comment: yea thats the question. so if its a non-integer i want to print an error message. but in this case, eventhough i enter an integer. it still prints the error message

Comment: The code works as long as you keep entering an integer value. It stops once you enter something other than an integer, by printing an error message.

Comment: yupp i know that. but in this case. i enter an integer. for example 10. it still prints the error message

Comment: this is the result for me. I don't know whether you copied the main method properly or not. `Enter Integer: 
2147483647
2147483646
2147483645
a
Not an integer, please try again
[2147483647, 2147483646, 2147483645]
`

Comment: see, that "not an integer, please try again" is printed. but it shouldnt because 2147483647 is an integer

Comment: Not an integer is printed after I entered `a`

Comment: ohh i think i know why. because i press enter with a blank input

Comment: I added 3 integers, then I entered an alphabet. Thats when the program stopped by saying a is not an integer and printed all the integers I entered (which is stored in the list)

Comment: I'm glad you found your mistake. If you can, accept the answer. Ciao!

Comment: because the initial idea was, to stop when i enter an empty input and then just pressing enter

Comment: @Kutam I updated the code in answer to work as you need. Press enter twice to exit. Else, print warning and keep on adding elements. Hope it works for you. Ciao!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you input a `String`,`reader.hasNextInt()` returns `false`, and the loop terminates. Therefore, **not printing anything**.

However, since it is a `do-while` loop, it **must execute once**, and therefore, if you input a `String` first, **then it prints out** the `error`

> This again, only happens if you press **Enter** after each input